# URL Domain Forwarding or Masking a Single Page?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, domain-forwarding, masking

I have a page on my WordPress site called **mysite.com/group** and it has a bunch of text content.

I want people to be able to access this page from the URL **mysitegroup.org** so it uses the mysite.com/group content but shows the .org URL in the address bar.

I'm a little confused how to handle this or what terminology (forwarding, masking, redirect) is used to describe what I'm trying to achieve, so it makes researching difficult because I'm not certain of the direction. Do I use forwarding with masking, as described here: [Manually Forwarding or Masking Your Domain Name](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forwarding-or-masking-your-domain-name-422) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to go about it is to transfer the files in the group folder at mysite.com to the document root folder at mysitegroup.org and make one of the HTML producing files by the name starting with index so that its executed. For example, make sure one file is index.htm or index.html or if you're using something like wordpress or another content management system, make sure one file is index.php.

If that is not an option then you need to create a script that redirects users from mysite.com/group to mysitegroup.org.

Easiest way to do it is to create index.php and save it in the group subfolder in the document root at mysite.com. The index.php should contain the following contents at minimum:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently",true);
header("Location: http://mysitegroup.org",true);
?>
```

Once the script is executed, users will be redirected to mysitegroup.org

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? Your first suggestion simply duplicates (manually) all the files (a WordPress site) from one location to the other. And the redirect would seem to be going the wrong way - the files are located at `mysite.com/group`. (But the OP wants to keep the `mysitegroup.org` domain visible, so a redirect either way would not be appropriate.)

Comment: I didn't think the OP wanted to make both URLs available to the public. I suggested a redirect based on this statement from the OP: I want people to be able to access this page from the URL mysitegroup.org so **it uses the mysite.com/group content but shows the .org URL in the address bar**. Because of that last statement, it hinted me to suggest using redirection.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Since I'm using WordPress and the content on mysite.com/group is a page titled 'group', where would there be a subfolder to place the index.php with 301 redirect? So this would redirect people from mysite.org to mysite.com/group, correct? Then how do I mask the URL address to be mysite.org in this case? Thank you for sharing your knowledge. :-)